# Trigger the Material TextField onChange from inner component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a component like:

```
class IncrementField extends Component {
inputRef;

changeValue() {
    this.inputRef.value = parseInt(this.inputRef.value) + 1;
}

render() {
    const { ...other } = this.props;

    return (
        <StyledField>
            <StyledButton onClick={this.changeValue.bind(this)}>-</StyledButton>
            <StyledTextField
                {...other}
                inputRef={input => (this.inputRef = input)}
                type={'number'}
                InputProps={{
                    readOnly: true,
                }}
            />
            <StyledButton onClick={this.changeValue.bind(this)}>+</StyledButton>
        </StyledField>
    )
}
}
```

It's purpose is to be used in a Formik form like

```
<IncrementField
        name={`fieldname`}
        key="fieldname"
        value={values.fieldname}
        onChange={changeAndSubmit.bind(this)}
        autoComplete="false">
    </IncrementField>
```

Its a component like

```
- 1 +
```

where you click on + and - and the value is incremented/decremented.

Sounds simple but I can't figure out how to change the value from the inside. StyledTextField is a @material-ui/core/TextField wrapped with styled-components.
What I want to do is to trigger the onChange event which is obviously passed in props and further placed with {...other}. I can change the value of the input, but it's probably not the way it should be done - because the onChange isnt triggered - and the Formik's form isnt changed.

I tried the approach I pasted, I tried also with having the value in state, but the onChange never fires... how to do that?

One way of doing that in Angular could be using an @Output() decorator, how does it look like in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value should always be saved by Formik - so if a change happens, you should call Formiks `handleChange` in your `changeValue` function.

`handleChange` takes a `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`, so you have to create a fake event and call the `handleChange` function with it.

```js
const evt = {target: {name: this.props.name, value: this.props.value + 1}}
this.props.handleChange(evt);
```

Comment: ok seems to work although I never liked that kind of fake event mocks. I thought there's maybe a cleaner way but I'll go with that for now, thanks